# Unknown user by Who in Debian

Tags: debian

When I tried to list all the login user by typing who to the terminal,
it returns the current user and a wired unknown user, as listed.

```
(unknown) :0           2016-08-04 12:02 (:0)
```

What is this user exactly?

Is it because the GUI was running as a login page in the physical computer?

Answer (score 0):

What it exactly means is that who has determined that there's some one on the console display, but either there's no record of it in `utmp`, or that the `UID` in `utmp` does not map to a known user in the password DB.  Of course the best way to find out about it is to go look at the GUI screen on the console.  But if that's hard (as in my case it's hundreds of miles away), you can research with a combination of `who /var/log/wtmp` and `last` (both of those print long lists, you'll more or less want to pipe their output and look around the date and time from bare `who`).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it seems to come from gdm3:

```
service gdm3 status          # reports the same date and time as who

service gdm3 stop  ; who     # clears the unknown login

service gdm3 start ; who     # the unknown login reappears
```

(the above commands were run as root)